# extract everything from SQL by 1 SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements, extract

I would like to extract everything from my SQL by 1 select.

I have table like this :

```
   client_id   | name  | company | number | stockfile | sum_pallets | time | 
      111      | Peter |   O2    | 77533  |    002S   |     121     | 11:00| 
      111      | Peter |   O2    | 77534  |    002S   |     42      | 11:00| 
      111      | Peter |   O2    | 77535  |    002S   |     85      | 11:00| 
      111      | Peter |   O2    | 77533  |    002S   |     215     | 10:00| 
      181      | Steven|   Call2 | 89555  |    S2S    |     150     | 11:00| 
      181      | Steven|   Call2 | 89559  |    S2S    |     80      | 10:00|
```

I use this code for select from sql - 
`$supplier = mysql_query("SELECT * from table")`

And Now i need something like this for extract -

`while($record = MySQL_Fetch_Array($supplier) WHERE Time = "10:00" AND Name = "PETER"):`

So i will get :

only 1 record with all colums for time 10:00 and name PETER.

Can someone help me?

I do not want use more than 1 select.

Comment: What's the expected behaviour, result ?

Comment: Result - every row with all columns, where is name - "peter" and time "10:00"

Comment: 111 | Peter| O2 | 77533 | 002S | 215 | 10:00|

Comment: I don't get why you want to filter in PHP the results from the query that is the most inefficient way to do it. if you run two queries it will be ways more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this :

```
$supplier = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($supplier)) {
  if ($record['Name'] == "Peter" && $record['Time'] == "10:00") {
    // Here's Peter with time 10:00
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear, i need to stay use only this one select - $supplier = mysql_query("SELECT * from table")